# Can JHipster be used to integrate e-commerce with marketplace?

Tags: rest, api, jhipster, marketplace

I am wondering if this project can be created using JHipster, or I am way over my head.

I need to create an integrator for e-commerce that will have many clients, and each clients will have their own products. Than the app will post all client's products on different marketplaces connecting to them via RESTful API.

I just need to know if it has been done before or I should look for a different approach on how to build this.

And if it's possible where can I find the entities (in JDL, or architecture) for the relationships of client/products database.